# variable does not get passed on to directive scope?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to pass on my address to a directive called gmaps:

```
  restrict: 'EA',
    template: '<div class="gmaps"></div>',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
         address: '=address'
    },
```

the address is defined in the controller:

```
app.controller('MapCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.streetNumber = "12";
  $scope.streetName = "sussex street";
  $scope.city = "sydney";
  $scope.country = "australia";

  $scope.address = $scope.streetNumber + "," + $scope.streetName + "," + $scope.city + "," + $scope.country;

  console.log($scope.address);


});
```

When I try to check the address it is undefined:

```
 link: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
      console.log('address', scope.address);
```

The plunkr address is:http://plnkr.co/edit/CNSgfgTem0VH2RTgVPjn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this part:

```
scope: {
    address: '=address'
}
```

See the [updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/A1yxrFPMe2j2oSeZ60Gi?p=preview) (it is now doing what you intend).

I think whenever you do `address: '=address'`, it uses the **isolate scope** (see the angularjs docs for [directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) and Ctrl+F 'isolate scope').

You can test this by saying `console.log($scope)` in the controller, and `console.log(scope)` in the directive. You'll see that your `scope` IDs are both different (003 and 004), which shows that they are referring to two different scopes.

Whenever you remove `address: '=address'`, you can `console.log` the scope once again in both the directive and the controller, and you'll see that both IDs are now 003, which means they are both now referring to the same scope.

Comment: @user603007 This is correct, but... If you plan to use more than one gmaps element in your app you will have to create a separate controller for each one, or else they will overwrite each others' address and other info each time you create a new one. The idea of the isolate scope is that each gmaps element will have its own scope. If you used `=address` as you did before, you need only pass in a value for `address="123 Some Street"` on the html element representing the map, and that address will be bound to that map. That's the whole idea of the isolate scope.

Comment: @user603007 for example, in your markup you could have `<gmaps address="123 Some Avenue"></gmaps>` and then the address '123 Some Avenue' is bound to that particular element's scope.